# C# Parse CSV - wrong search

Tags: c#, csv

In CVS file I have a column with addresses IP.
When I try to find 100.100.100.2 that's not on the list, It find 100.100.100.21 etc. How I can search only this unique string?

Delimiter is ";"

I use:

```
    TextFieldParser sprawdz = new TextFieldParser("C:\\wykaz_druk.csv");
    string currentLine;
    string searchcsv = textBox_SPR_SEARCH.Text;
    sprawdz.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    sprawdz.Delimiters = new string[] { ";" };
    sprawdz.TrimWhiteSpace = true;


    do
    {
        currentLine = sprawdz.ReadLine();
        if (currentLine != null && currentLine.Contains(searchcsv))
        {
            string file = currentLine;
            string adresip = file.Split(';')[2].Trim();

            textBox2.Text = adresip;

        }
    }
    while (currentLine != null);
```

I also tried:

```
           .ReadLines("C:\\wykaz_druk.csv")
           .Where(line => line.Contains(NS)).FirstOfDefault();

                if (foundRecord != null)
                {
                    var cols = foundRecord.Split(';');
                    var status = cols[0];
...
```

Comment: Don't use `Contains("100.100.100.2 ")` if you want an exact match. If the field appears in the middle, you can use `;100.100.100.2;`. If this is the last column, try `EndsWith("100.100.100.2")`. If it's the first, try `StartsWith`

Comment: It's hard to answer this without knowing the structure of the CSV file. You should be parsing the IPs into a `List<>` of some kind, which you can then more easily search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.Contains` check if line contain specifed string. It is fully understand, that `"somestring".Contains("some")` is `true`. If that is the case, you will need first to get IP from csv, and then check if result exacly match your requested IP.

```
TextFieldParser sprawdz = new TextFieldParser("C:\\wykaz_druk.csv");
string currentLine;
string searchcsv = textBox_SPR_SEARCH.Text;
sprawdz.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
sprawdz.Delimiters = new string[] { ";" };
sprawdz.TrimWhiteSpace = true;


do
{
    currentLine = sprawdz.ReadLine();
    if (currentLine != null)
    {
        string file = currentLine;
        string adresip = file.Split(';')[2].Trim();
        if(adresip == searchcsv)
        {
            textBox2.Text = adresip;
        }
    }
}
while (currentLine != null);
```

Comment: It's works :)
I also checked if it works when I want to search for something else.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you check the entire line because you want to avoid generating a lot of substrings. `Contains` though, will match any line that contains that particular IP address.

The trick is to force `Contains` to search for a single field match. If the IP field appears in the middle of the line, you can add the delimiters to each side, eg:

```
var searchCSV= String.Format(";{0};",textBox_SPR_SEARCH.Text);
// or 
// var searchCSV= $";{textBox_SPR_SEARCH.Text};";

if(currentLine?.Contains(searchcsv) == true)
{
    string file = currentLine;
    string adresip = file.Split(';')[2].Trim();
    ...
}
```

If the field appears at the start of the line, use `StartsWith` with only an ending delimiter :

```
var searchCSV= $"{textBox_SPR_SEARCH.Text};";
if(currentLine?.StartsWith(searchcsv) == true)
...
```

If it's the last field, use `EndsWith` with only a starting delimiter

```
var searchCSV= $";{textBox_SPR_SEARCH.Text}";
if(currentLine?.EndsWith(searchcsv) == true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Equals in an inner check

```
    if (currentLine != null && currentLine.Contains(searchcsv))
    {
        string file = currentLine;
        string adresip = file.Split(';')[2].Trim();

        if(adresip.Equals(searchcsv))
            textBox2.Text = adresip;

    }
```